# My react app appears blank after successfully deploying to github-pages

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, github, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a react app **without any routing functionality. Just  a single page app** to github pages and everything worked successfully. I did'nt get any error while deploying but after deployment, the app is blank and when i check my console i see the following error

```
    GET https://vicktor61.github.io/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git/static/css/main.aea680b0.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
vicktor61.github.io/:1 GET https://vicktor61.github.io/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git/static/js/2.ed9a5867.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
vicktor61.github.io/:1 GET https://vicktor61.github.io/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git/static/js/main.0913b291.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git/manifest.json:1 GET https://vicktor61.github.io/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git/manifest.json 404
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

I understand that the issue probably is because the gh-pages server could not get my files. But i still don't know why. please i will really appreciate a well detailed response.

**This is my app link**
https://vicktor61.github.io/indecision-sniffle/

**and this is my package.json file**

```
{
  "homepage": "https://github.com/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git",
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.3",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "uniqid": "^5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is my github page where the whole app is hosted
https://github.com/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle/

Comment: Did you follow along this guide? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#github-pages

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202266/build-version-of-react-app-giving-wrong-links-to-css-and-js-files It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As per the official [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths), setting the `homepage` setting as follows in your `package.json` should fix the issue:

```
"homepage": ".",
```

In the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths) it is stated:

> This will make sure that all the asset paths are relative to
> index.html. You will then be able to move your app from
> `http://mywebsite.com` to `http://mywebsite.com/relativepath` or even
> `http://mywebsite.com/relative/path` without having to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing by the errors on the github page, the page is trying to load files which can't be found. I would say your homepage is wrong. It shouldn't be

```json
"homepage": "https://github.com/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git",
```

it should be

```json
"homepage": "https://vicktor61.github.io/indecision-sniffle",
```

as the page tries to load for example this file

```
https://vicktor61.github.io/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle.git/static/css/main.aea680b0.chunk.css
```

while it should be this file

```
https://vicktor61.github.io/indecision-sniffle/static/css/main.aea680b0.chunk.css
```

Comment: i did that and redeployed my app but still with the same issue

Comment: When you say "redeploy", did you build again or just pushed a different package.json? It is still trying to load from the wrong domain https://vicktor61.github.io/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle/static/css/main.aea680b0.chunk.css

Comment: I built again and then i pushed the new code to the repo then i regenerates the github page but at the end i got the same error

Comment: Okay, if you did all what you say I have no clue what didn't work

Comment: Here the homepage is still wrong btw https://github.com/VickTor61/indecision-sniffle/blob/master/package.json#L2

Comment: Please what's supposed to be the correct homepage

Comment: Please what's supposed to be the correct homepage

Comment: @EnomaVictor it says so in my answer, please read carefully.